# Make a kubernetes pod ready after delay

Tags: kubernetes-pod, readinessprobe

I want to run a bash script inside a pod which takes 20 sec. to complete. I want the pod to be ready and be added to service endpoint  only after that script finishes. How can i do that ?

Comment: have it create a file and have the readiness probe check for the existence of that file?